# New to Angular 4. How do I bind my data to the form?

Tags: angular, data-binding

new to angular and I can't quite figure out how to bind my data to the form. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Here's my emp-info.ts:

```html
export class EmpInfo {
    EmpKey: number;
    EmpID: string;
    Firstname: string;
    LastName: string;
    EmpStat: string;
    StartDate: Date;
    AdjustedStart: Date;
    Anniversary: number;
    PTOYear: number;
    STDLTD: number;
    Uncharged: number;
    ETOEarned: number;
    ETORequests: number;
    ETORemaining: number;
    PTOBase: number;
    PTOCarry: number;
    PTOBorrowed: number;
    PTOBalance: number;
    PTORequests: number;
    PTORemaining: number;
}
```

Here's my emp-info.service.ts:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';


import { EmpInfo } from './emp-info';

@Injectable()

export class EmpInfoService {
    private empInfoUrl = 'api/EmpInfo';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getEmpInfos(): Promise<EmpInfo[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.empInfoUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || {};
    }


    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

Here's my summary.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { EmpInfoService } from './emp-info.service';

import { EmpInfo } from './emp-info'; 

@Component({
    selector: 'pto-summary',
    templateUrl: `./summary.component.html`,
    styleUrls: ['./summary.component.css']
})

export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit{
    empInfo: EmpInfo[];

    constructor(private empInfoService: EmpInfoService) { }

    getEmpInfo(): void {
        this.empInfoService.getEmpInfos().then(
            empInfo => this.empInfo = empInfo
        );
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getEmpInfo();
    }
}
```

and then here's the form that I would like to insert them into:

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">JOHNSON Summary</h3>
    <div style="float: right;">
      <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
          <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
          <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="overflow-x:auto;">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Status </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <select class="form-control" id="empStatus">
                <option value="" disabled>Choose Type....</option>
                <option value="Current">Current</option>
                <option value="Terminated">Terminated</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Anniversary </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empAnniversary" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Start Date </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <input class='form-control' type="date" id="empStartDate" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Adjusted Start </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <input class='form-control' type="date" id="empAdjustedStart" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> STD/LTD </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empSTDLTD" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Uncharged </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empUncharged" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>


      <fieldset>

        <h4>PTO</h4>
        <br />

        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            <label class="col-xs-2"> Base </label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBase" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-2" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#43; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Carryover </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoCarryover" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Balance </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBalance" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-2" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#8213; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Borrowed </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBorrowed" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr style="border: solid 1px black;border-bottom:1px solid black;clear:both" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-1" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#8213; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Requests </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoRequests" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
          </div>
          <hr style="border: solid 1px black;border-bottom:1px solid black;clear:both" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-2" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#61; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Balance </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBalance" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-1" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#61; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Available </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoAvailable" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>


      <fieldset>

        <h4>ETO</h4>
        <br />

          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
              <label class="col-xs-4"> Earned </label>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="etoEarned" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-xs-2"> &#8213; </label>
              <label class="col-xs-4"> Requests </label>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="etoRequested" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr style="border: solid 1px black;border-bottom:1px solid black;clear:both" />
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-xs-2"> &#61; </label>
              <label class="col-xs-4"> Available </label>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="etoAvailable" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6"></div>

      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to insert them into where each of the fields is. I've tried {{empInfo.field}} but that hasn't seemed to work. Thanks in advance

Comment: where is #f="ngForm" in form and also there is no ngModel binding that will bind data for you .check this link 


https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-template-driven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updating answer to support empInfo as an array and display single item in the form.**

We need to store a reference to which empInfo item in the array we are going to display on the form. You can either store the selectedIndex or the selectedEmpInfo.

Here is how to do the selectedIndex approach:

Create a selected index attribute in your component:

```
export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit{
    empInfo: EmpInfo[];
    selectedIndex = 0;
```

Template change. Note: I added a *ngIf to do a check on the empInfo array. If you do not do this, you might get an error in your console.

```
      <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedIndex">
        <label class="col-xs-2" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#43; </label>
        <label class="col-xs-4"> Carryover </label>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoCarryover" [(ngModel)]="empInfo[selectedIndex].PTOCarry"/>
        </div>
      </div>
```

---

**Original answer before edit**

If the empInfo is an array (since you had empInfo declared as an array in your code), wrap your form inside a *ngFor like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let emp of empInfo">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-2" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#43; </label>
        <label class="col-xs-4"> Carryover </label>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoCarryover" [(ngModel)]="emp.PTOCarry"/>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

If the empInfo is a single instance (assuming the empInfo being declared as an array in your code was a typo), do this:

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-2" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#43; </label>
        <label class="col-xs-4"> Carryover </label>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoCarryover" [(ngModel)]="empInfo.PTOCarry"/>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: thanks! But, it's only one form and I'll be picking specific instances of the array so would I need something like <label> Anniversary </label> <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empAnniversary" value={{empInfo[0].Anniversary}} /> ?

Comment: Use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `value='{{}}'` I've updated my answer to support array with a single item display. Also, I've put in an *ngIf to make sure there are no errors in the console.

Comment: I'm actually getting an error that says "Cannot read property 0 of undefined" which is talking about the selectedIndex variable. How would I handle that?

Comment: There was a bug in the *ngIf code, I've updated it to say `*ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedIndex"`

Comment: Did you try putting in the `*ngIf` ? I put in the`*ngIf` specifically to avoid this error.

Comment: I didn't put it in at first because I figured if I put the index as an index that I knew existed in my array, it would still work and then I'd go from there. But, I put it in now and it worked. Thanks a lot, it's much appreciated!

Comment: You are welcome. FYI, the reason we need that `*ngIf` check is because, the web service call to populate the array would not have completed when the UI template is being rendered.

Comment: oh okay, that makes sense. I should've thought of that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have return array of empInfo from service.
So you have array of empInfo so binding to array to form you have to use

*ngFor="let item of empInfo"

or

if it is single form then you should use {{empInfo[0].field}}